# How can I make this series of java script variables into a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, pug

I am using node.js and the excel parser xlsx to do this. I have 3 different sheets in my example excel file. My code so far finds all the sheet names, and then the data in the sheet and then finds the data in the cell A1 based on which sheet I choose to find it in, in this case it's the sheet at index [0].

I want to be able to find this data in cell A1 but not by having to manually input which sheet, as I want the client to be able to choose the sheet from a drop down menu(which I already have the code for) and then have it show the data in A1 based on which sheet they pick. Therefore I was wondering how I could turn my code into a function so that instead of having [0], it is able to find the data in A1 based on the variable that is the client's pick from the menu.

```
  var workbook = xlsx.readFile('C:/Users/user/Desktop/1234.xlsx');

  var sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
  var address_of_cell = 'A1';
  var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheet_name];
  var desired_cell = worksheet[address_of_cell];
  var desired_value = desired_cell.v;
  console.log(desired_value);
```

(the .v is just an input with the xlsx parser that presents the data as raw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a function out of it. If this isn't what you were asking for, please clarify a bit.

```
function getSheetData(workbook, sheetNumber, cellName) {
  var workbook = xlsx.readFile(workbook);
  var sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[sheetNumber];
  var address_of_cell = cellName;
  var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheet_name];
  var desired_cell = worksheet[address_of_cell];
  var desired_value = desired_cell.v;
  return desired_value;
}

// get the variables from the user input, and then run
// this.
var data = getSheetData('1234.xlsx', 0, 'A1');
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted. I'm just new to coding and didn't know how exactly I would turn it into a function with arguments, etc. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Good luck on your journey. :)